# RSA creation time, why drop after 16384bit?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

i was playing around with RSA Key creation and start to measure the time it takes to create RSA key with a specific bit strength.
My key question was, how long does it take to create a 16384 bit RSA key (around 140s).
I expected a steady logarithmic increase, but I got this: (x: bit; y: seconds)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

All keys are created with:
     csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keyStrength); (c#, net 4.0)
So why did I get this sawtooth wave?

Comment: What is the horizontal axis?

Comment: strength in bits, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zseyf239.aspx

Comment: I doubt lengths greater than 16384 are even supported.

Comment: Please don't provide binaries for download. If you want someone to pay attention to your questions provide source code.

Comment: My experiments show that an exception is thrown when the keysize specified is >= 16385.

Comment: You are right, binaries are evil ;) Here is the 'very small' programm http://pastebin.com/rYsPg2tp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly the graph implies they are not producing primes by doing the classical primality test of randomly generated numbers for each prime to produce the RSA key.

So, the only thing left to assume is that they used some sort of primes families generator which works in pre-segmented ranges.

You can read more here:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-can-i-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa

Comment: Is it not a secruity issue to use methods like you link provided? And not just test each random number for prime?

Comment: of course it is. is it making you feel less safe when you buy over the internet? maybe.. will you stop buying things from the internet - of course not. summary: result= scientists celebrate, developers 99% happy unless they understand what you understood, secret agencies extra happy, hackers - extremely happy.. where's the problem? :) ask yourself - is it really need to be safe or just give that impression?
Not to confuse- RSA is safe, the way it is implemented world wide - well, that's a different thing :)

Comment: The graph is incorrect. If you specify an RSA modulus > 16384 an exception is thrown, no primes are generated at all.